# Recursive call with private method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, methods, private

Why does this code work? I understand that `private` works as a modifier for a method and using an explicit reciever (`self`) won't work.

I know that there will be a SystemStackError, but I want to understand the concept of visibility.

```
class Methods
    private
    def private_method
        puts "I'm in private method"
        self.private_method
    end
end
class ChildMethods < Methods
    def private_method
        super
    end
end
ChildMethods.new.private_method
```

Comment: The fact that `Methods#private_method` is private is a bit of a red-herring. `ChildMethods#private_method` causes Ruby to send `private_method` to `self` in the parent class. Which `private_method`? It first looks to see if there is one in `self`'s class. What is `self`? It's an instance of `ChildMethods`, of course (add a `puts` statement in `Methods#private_method` if you're not sure), so Ruby finds and executes `ChildMethods#private_method`, sending it back to the parent. btw, `self.` in `self.private_method` adds nothing, as the receiver is assumed to be `self` if it is not explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `private_method` methods, one in the superclass (that is private) and an overriden one in the subclass (that is public).

Your code works because the `self.private_method` in the superclass isn't calling its own private `private_method`, but the one that is public in the subclass.

This, for example, will not work:

```
Methods.new.send(:private_method)
```

Comment: How does that work? Why is it calling the subclass method and not its own?

Comment: That is the way it works every time: when you call a method on `self` (either explicitly or implicitly) the method lookup will always start at the most specific subclass, and work its way up the superclasses/modules until it is found. In your case `private_method` is found immediately in `ChildMethods` (which is a public method).

Comment: Right, but if I made  in the Methods class a public_method that calls the private_method, this would crash on the self.private_method because i'm standing directly on the Methods class if I make this call:

Methods.new.public_method

Comment: Right, because on `Methods` the method is private, and you can't call a private method explicitly. That's why I pointed out in my answer that `Methods.new.send(:private_method)` will not work.

Comment: Exactly, it will print one time this:
"I'm in private method"
Then it will fail

Answer (score 1):

Private method could not be called for **explicit** receiver, but could for **implicit** one, as you do. In other words, an object can call -other object- superclass private method as it exists in its own context.

That also works fine due to there are no explicit receivers

```
  1 class Methods
  2     private
  3     def private_method
  4         puts "I'm in private method"
  5         private_method
  6     end
  7 end
  8 class ChildMethods < Methods
  9     def public_method
 10       private_method
 11     end
 12 end
 13 ChildMethods.new.public_method
```

But this throws the error since `self` is an explicit receiver.

```
  1 class Methods
  2     private
  3     def private_method
  4         puts "I'm in private method"
  5         self.private_method # <-------------------------
  6     end
  7 end
  8 class ChildMethods < Methods
  9     def public_method
 10       private_method
 11     end
 12 end
 13 ChildMethods.new.public_method

Press ENTER or type command to continue
I'm in private method
1.rb:5:in `private_method': private method `private_method' called for #<ChildMethods:0x00000101084290> (NoMethodError)
        from 1.rb:10:in `public_method'
        from 1.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

And that works fine too:

```
  1 class Methods
  2     private
  3     def private_method
  4         puts "I'm in private method"
  5         self.public_method # <-------------------------
  6     end
  7 end
  8 class ChildMethods < Methods
  9     def public_method
 10       private_method
 11     end
 12 end
 13 ChildMethods.new.public_method
```

Comment: you mean that when I'm calling from the ChildMethods, i have set the "context" of the caller and when I call private_method again, it will go down to the child and call it again? Because of the context from where i'm standing.

Comment: Basically yes. *It will go down to the child* - it takes self, and sends the message. It uses "implicit receiver" way to send a message using current context if you doesn't specify a receiver, and that way calling a method doesn't take into account message visibility aspect.